# ffplay: how does it calculate the fps for playback?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I'm trying to playback a live media (h264) which is produced by a hardware encoder.

The actual desired FPS on the encoder is set to **20**, and when checking the logs of the encoder it prints "FPS statistics" every minute:

```
2020-10-21 17:26:54.787 [  info] video_stream_thread(),video chn 0, fps: 19.989270
2020-10-21 17:27:54.836 [  info] video_stream_thread(),video chn 0, fps: 19.989270
2020-10-21 17:28:54.837 [  info] video_stream_thread(),video chn 0, fps: 20.005924
2020-10-21 17:29:54.837 [  info] video_stream_thread(),video chn 0, fps: 19.989270
2020-10-21 17:30:54.888 [  info] video_stream_thread(),video chn 0, fps: 19.989274
2020-10-21 17:31:54.918 [  info] video_stream_thread(),video chn 0, fps: 19.989264
```

You can see it's varying, but not too much around 20.

**Question1:** Is this normal? Or it should be exactly 20 every time? To avoid confusion: I'd like to know if by the standard of H264, can this be accepted as a valid stream or this violates some
rule?

I'm trying to playback this stream with `ffplay`:

```
$ ffplay rtsp://this_stream
Input #0, rtsp, from 'xyz'
  Metadata:
    title           : 
    comment         : substream
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.040000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 640x360, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

The thing is that ffplay thinks this is a stream with 25fps. And it also plays 25 frames each sec, causing the stream to stall and buffer in every few seconds.

I believe the fps is calculated by some pts/dts values in the stream itself, and it's not hardcoded. Am I wrong here?

If I'm not wrong, why does ffplay thinks this stream runs at 25fps, whereas it only runs at (around) 20?

Comment: Raw H.264 streams have no timestamps, so ffmpeg assigns 25 fps as default. Assign wallclock timestamps.

Comment: If they don't have timestamps, how framerate is preset in case of a H264 stream? (How shall the player know the framerate?)

Comment: How can I change ffplay's default to 20? Note ffplay does not have the same parameters as ffmpeg.

Comment: *how framerate is preset in case of a H264 stream?* --> it isn't preset, it's assigned. Apply a `setpts=N/20/TB` filter in ffplay.

Comment: It plays nicely, however still prints 25fps in the stream info line. Is this something I should not worry about? You wrote this as answer for another question: "Raw H.264 streams do not have PTS values. They do have a framerate". So H264 do have a framerate but it's assigned? Assigned by whom?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't change anything: "setpts=N/10/TB" plays at the exact same speed as with 20.

Comment: Assigned by ffmpeg. Share full log of 10 fps attempt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223452/discussion-between-daniel-and-gyan).